# Storage destination needs to have a Service SAS, not an Account SAS. What Does This Mean?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Hello recently I have been in the process of trying to use this azure graph request noted here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-exportpersonaldata?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Now when you do that request as stated in it you provide a storage location which is, "This is a shared access signature (SAS) URL to an Azure Storage account, to where data should be exported."

Every time I provide by SAS url I get this error, "Storage destination needs to have a Service SAS, not an Account SAS"

Can someone please help me understand what this means? The documentation it links is not clear.

Comment: Can you share the SAS URL that you're providing. Please obfuscate account name and sig portion of the URL.

Comment: The one I am currently trying to use is this  https://myaccounnt.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&sr=b&se=2020-02-13T17:39:31Z&st=2020-02-13T09:39:31Z&spr=https&sig=sighere

Comment: `The one I am currently trying to use is this` - I think you forgot to include the SAS URL :).

Comment: I updated it should have the url now, if it doesnt show on your end here it is https://myaccounnt.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&sr=b&se=2020-02-13T17:39:31Z&st=2020-02-13T09:39:31Z&spr=https&sig=sighere

Comment: Provided an answer. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Storage destination needs to have a Service SAS, not an Account SAS

Difference between `Account SAS` and `Service SAS` is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature#types-of-shared-access-signatures.

You're providing an SAS URL for the entire account (e.g. `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/?sas-parameters`) whereas it is expected that you provide a SAS URL for a specific blob container (e.g. `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/blob-container/?sas-parameters`).

There are two possible solutions:

1. Create a SAS URL for a specific blob container. Or in other words create a Service SAS as the error message is telling you to do. You can do so using a tool like Microsoft Storage Explorer.
2. Insert the blob container name in your account SAS URL so that it looks like something like this `https://account.blob.core.windows.net/blob-container/?sas-parameters`.

Please note that if you're using an Account SAS, it should at least have `Write` permission on `Object` for `Blob` service.

Comment: How do you create a SAS URL for a specific blob container on the azure portal? Everytime I go to the blob container there is no area for me to do this on azure.

Comment: For some reason I thought that this functionality already exist in portal but I was wrong. Sorry about that. You can use Microsoft's Storage Explorer to do generate a Service SAS on a container.

Comment: As a quick check, you can simply go with solution #2 I mentioned.

Comment: but now it seems I need the User.Export.All permission in order to actually do the api request, but microsofts graph doesnt even have this permission listed as one to grant to my account, so essentially this feature is useless.